# CMAKE How to compile static/object library with different flags

Tags: cmake

Problem: 2 executables, 1 core library with if/defs inside

**UPD2** after help from Ľubomír Carik

Each executable sets up own preprocessor flags
At the beginning, target for library is created

```
add_library(common_library STATIC ${__SOURCES} ${__HEADERS})
```

*common_library* code (which is static library, own cmake file) has preprocessor conditions

```
#if defined(MY_DEFINE_1)
// specific code #1 
#elif defined (MY_DEFINE_2)
// specific code #2 
#else
// error
#endif
```

I have problems with CMake to prepare such a configuration. Library doesn't see defines. 
**First executable** (own cmake):

```
target_compile_definitions(common_library PRIVATE -DMY_DEFINE_1)
add_executable(BINARY_1  ${bin1_sources}   )
add_dependencies(BINARY_1 common_library)
```

**Second executable** (own cmake):

```
target_compile_definitions(common_library PRIVATE -DMY_DEFINE_2)
add_executable(BINARY_2  ${bin2_sources}   )
add_dependencies(BINARY_2 common_library)
```

But *common_library* is built only once, with 2 defines. It should be built separately for each binary.

Comment: Your title is about *STATIC* libraries, your code refers to *OBJECT* library (`TARGET_OBJECTS` property), and your text notes *SHARED* library (`... which will build shared library 2 times`). Which type of the library you actually use?

Comment: by "shared" i mean, that code is shared. STATIC or OBJECT, I have no idea, what will work. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to change the compiler flags on the library, you'll need to build the library multiple times.  What you're doing right now is changing the flags on the library multiple times, which is why you're seeing both sets of compiler definitions in the build.

The simplest way to solve your problem is to just create two library entries, each with their own flags.  Here's the smallest example I can think of:

```
project("sample"
    LANGUAGES
        C
)

add_library(lib1 STATIC foo.c)
target_compile_definitions(lib1
    PRIVATE -DCOND=1
)
add_library(lib2 STATIC foo.c)
target_compile_definitions(lib2
      PRIVATE -DCOND=0
)
```

My `foo.c` looks like this:

```
#if COND
#warning "case 1"
#else
#warning "case 2"
#endif

void foo() { }
```

The build looks like this:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target lib1
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/lib1.dir/foo.o
/tmp/so/static-lib/foo.c:2:2: warning: #warning "case 1" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "case 1"
  ^~~~~~~
[ 50%] Linking C static library liblib1.a
[ 50%] Built target lib1
Scanning dependencies of target lib2
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/lib2.dir/foo.o
/tmp/so/static-lib/foo.c:4:2: warning: #warning "case 2" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "case 2"
  ^~~~~~~
[100%] Linking C static library liblib2.a
[100%] Built target lib2
```

If most of the library code is the same, you can limit the amount of compilation time by using three libraries (e.g., truly common code, then libraries that only contain conditional compilation stuff).

Comment: Thanks, finally I came to the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [target_compile_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) and [target_compile_definitions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) instead of global 'add_definitions'. And set different defines for library_1 and library_2.

Comment: Ok, it helped, I just had to change OBJECT to STATIC

Comment: I have to unmark answer, since it works, but ... strange. Finally I have both defines in library. And it is built only 1 time, with both flags.

Comment: Yes, I see now, your changes. When you add next define to the same target it is like addition. You need 2 targets i.e. 2 libraries with different target names (aka common_library1 and common_library2). Please don't aim to CMakeList.txt files as a sequence of commands. CMake will generate project files and these are living their own life.

Comment: u should create lib1 and lib2, then binary1 and binary2 targets and then u can use "target_link_libraries" to link lib1 to app1 (instead of redundant add_dependencies) etc.