# Build twice same library

Tags: cmake, build, shared-libraries

So I'm building a library, it's basically same code base, but I need to build it twice, the only difference is the second show compile with a -D option, and they need to produce two different artifact. Currently I have this:

```
add_library(foo STATIC sources...)
add_library(foo.ex STATIC sources...)
target_compile_definitions(foo.ex PUBLIC FOO)
```

Is this the best way? Is there any other better ways to do?

Comment: Have you searched other questions with the similar problem? E.g. have you seen [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979770/cmake-how-to-compile-static-object-library-with-different-flags)?

Comment: my question is slightly different, because i'd like to duplicate all the other options and flags in one call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the best way? Is there any other better ways to do?

Yes, I think this is the best way. I would only refactor and places sources in a common variable so they are not repeated:

```
set(sources sources...)
add_library(foo STATIC ${sources})
add_library(foo.ex STATIC ${sources})
target_compile_definitions(foo.ex PUBLIC FOO)
```